# Marking body as abstract C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to mark a body as abstract:

```
 public static int getpeername(IntPtr s, ref NativeSocketMethode.sockaddr Address, ref int namelen);
```

I currently get this error:

```
Error   1   'NativeMethodes.NativeSocketMethode.getpeername(System.IntPtr, ref NativeMethodes.NativeSocketMethode.sockaddr, ref int)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\NativeMethodes.cs    13  23  WindowsFormsApplication2
```

Comment: -1 for documenting your question so poorly and giving nobody a chance to guess the correct answer.  You must use a pinvoke declaration with the [DllImport] attribute and the *extern* keyword.  The function lives in ws2_32.dll.  Frankly, you'll never get this going without learning a lot more about C# interop programming.  Or using System.Net, there isn't any point in pinvoking this.  Socket.RemoteEndPoint property.

Answer (score 5):

You are not going to to be able to mark a method as both abstract and static.

Answer (score 2):

Static method cannot be abstract.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a code body on a static method, like this:

```
public static int getpeername(IntPtr s, ref NativeSocketMethode.sockaddr Address, ref int namelen)
{
    return 0; // This, of course, should actually do some logic.
}
```